# How can I optimize these huge queries?

Tags: apex, soql, query

I'm concerned that some code in my production environment isn't as efficient as it can be. We're coming close to governor limits but I don't know exactly how to proceed with optimizing.

```
public void getPerformanceCounts() {

    MFClosedToday = [SELECT count() from Case Where Assignee__c =: 'MF' AND Status = 'Solved' AND ClosedDate >= : chartRange[0]]; 
    MFClosed1DayPrevious = [SELECT count() from Case Where Assignee__c =: 'MF' AND Status = 'Solved' AND ClosedDate <: chartRange[0] AND ClosedDate >= : system.today().addDays(-1)]; 
    MFClosed2DayPrevious = [SELECT count() from Case Where Assignee__c =: 'MF' AND Status = 'Solved' AND ClosedDate <: system.today().addDays(-1) AND ClosedDate >= : system.today().addDays(-2)]; 
    MFClosed3DayPrevious = [SELECT count() from Case Where Assignee__c =: 'MF' AND Status = 'Solved' AND ClosedDate <: system.today().addDays(-2) AND ClosedDate >= : system.today().addDays(-3)]; 
    MFClosed4DayPrevious = [SELECT count() from Case Where Assignee__c =: 'MF' AND Status = 'Solved' AND ClosedDate <: system.today().addDays(-3) AND ClosedDate >= : system.today().addDays(-4)]; 
    MFClosed5DayPrevious = [SELECT count() from Case Where Assignee__c =: 'MF' AND Status = 'Solved' AND ClosedDate <: system.today().addDays(-4) AND ClosedDate >= : system.today().addDays(-5)]; 
    MFClosed6DayPrevious = [SELECT count() from Case Where Assignee__c =: 'MF' AND Status = 'Solved' AND ClosedDate <: system.today().addDays(-5) AND ClosedDate >= : system.today().addDays(-6)]; 
    MFClosed7DayPrevious = [SELECT count() from Case Where Assignee__c =: 'MF' AND Status = 'Solved' AND ClosedDate <: system.today().addDays(-6) AND ClosedDate >  : system.today().addDays(-7)];

    RMClosedToday = [SELECT count() from Case Where Assignee__c =: 'RM' AND Status = 'Solved' AND ClosedDate >= : chartRange[0]]; 
    RMClosed1DayPrevious = [SELECT count() from Case Where Assignee__c =: 'RM' AND Status = 'Solved' AND ClosedDate <: chartRange[0] AND ClosedDate >= : system.today().addDays(-1)]; 
    RMClosed2DayPrevious = [SELECT count() from Case Where Assignee__c =: 'RM' AND Status = 'Solved' AND ClosedDate <: system.today().addDays(-1) AND ClosedDate >= : system.today().addDays(-2)]; 
    RMClosed3DayPrevious = [SELECT count() from Case Where Assignee__c =: 'RM' AND Status = 'Solved' AND ClosedDate <: system.today().addDays(-2) AND ClosedDate >= : system.today().addDays(-3)]; 
    RMClosed4DayPrevious = [SELECT count() from Case Where Assignee__c =: 'RM' AND Status = 'Solved' AND ClosedDate <: system.today().addDays(-3) AND ClosedDate >= : system.today().addDays(-4)]; 
    RMClosed5DayPrevious = [SELECT count() from Case Where Assignee__c =: 'RM' AND Status = 'Solved' AND ClosedDate <: system.today().addDays(-4) AND ClosedDate >= : system.today().addDays(-5)]; 
    RMClosed6DayPrevious = [SELECT count() from Case Where Assignee__c =: 'RM' AND Status = 'Solved' AND ClosedDate <: system.today().addDays(-5) AND ClosedDate >= : system.today().addDays(-6)]; 
    RMClosed7DayPrevious = [SELECT count() from Case Where Assignee__c =: 'RM' AND Status = 'Solved' AND ClosedDate <: system.today().addDays(-6) AND ClosedDate >  : system.today().addDays(-7)];

    GTClosedToday = [SELECT count() from Case Where Assignee__c =: 'GT' AND Status = 'Solved' AND ClosedDate >= : chartRange[0]]; 
    GTClosed1DayPrevious = [SELECT count() from Case Where Assignee__c =: 'GT' AND Status = 'Solved' AND ClosedDate <: chartRange[0] AND ClosedDate >= : system.today().addDays(-1)]; 
    GTClosed2DayPrevious = [SELECT count() from Case Where Assignee__c =: 'GT' AND Status = 'Solved' AND ClosedDate <: system.today().addDays(-1) AND ClosedDate >= : system.today().addDays(-2)]; 
    GTClosed3DayPrevious = [SELECT count() from Case Where Assignee__c =: 'GT' AND Status = 'Solved' AND ClosedDate <: system.today().addDays(-2) AND ClosedDate >= : system.today().addDays(-3)]; 
    GTClosed4DayPrevious = [SELECT count() from Case Where Assignee__c =: 'GT' AND Status = 'Solved' AND ClosedDate <: system.today().addDays(-3) AND ClosedDate >= : system.today().addDays(-4)]; 
    GTClosed5DayPrevious = [SELECT count() from Case Where Assignee__c =: 'GT' AND Status = 'Solved' AND ClosedDate <: system.today().addDays(-4) AND ClosedDate >= : system.today().addDays(-5)]; 
    GTClosed6DayPrevious = [SELECT count() from Case Where Assignee__c =: 'GT' AND Status = 'Solved' AND ClosedDate <: system.today().addDays(-5) AND ClosedDate >= : system.today().addDays(-6)]; 
    GTClosed7DayPrevious = [SELECT count() from Case Where Assignee__c =: 'GT' AND Status = 'Solved' AND ClosedDate <: system.today().addDays(-6) AND ClosedDate >  : system.today().addDays(-7)];

    CWClosedToday = [SELECT count() from Case Where Assignee__c =: 'CW' AND Status = 'Solved' AND ClosedDate >= : chartRange[0]]; 
    CWClosed1DayPrevious = [SELECT count() from Case Where Assignee__c =: 'CW' AND Status = 'Solved' AND ClosedDate <: chartRange[0] AND ClosedDate >= : system.today().addDays(-1)]; 
    CWClosed2DayPrevious = [SELECT count() from Case Where Assignee__c =: 'CW' AND Status = 'Solved' AND ClosedDate <: system.today().addDays(-1) AND ClosedDate >= : system.today().addDays(-2)]; 
    CWClosed3DayPrevious = [SELECT count() from Case Where Assignee__c =: 'CW' AND Status = 'Solved' AND ClosedDate <: system.today().addDays(-2) AND ClosedDate >= : system.today().addDays(-3)]; 
    CWClosed4DayPrevious = [SELECT count() from Case Where Assignee__c =: 'CW' AND Status = 'Solved' AND ClosedDate <: system.today().addDays(-3) AND ClosedDate >= : system.today().addDays(-4)]; 
    CWClosed5DayPrevious = [SELECT count() from Case Where Assignee__c =: 'CW' AND Status = 'Solved' AND ClosedDate <: system.today().addDays(-4) AND ClosedDate >= : system.today().addDays(-5)]; 
    CWClosed6DayPrevious = [SELECT count() from Case Where Assignee__c =: 'CW' AND Status = 'Solved' AND ClosedDate <: system.today().addDays(-5) AND ClosedDate >= : system.today().addDays(-6)]; 
    CWClosed7DayPrevious = [SELECT count() from Case Where Assignee__c =: 'CW' AND Status = 'Solved' AND ClosedDate <: system.today().addDays(-6) AND ClosedDate >  : system.today().addDays(-7)];

}
```

I can't think of any ways to do this any better. Can somebody give me some pointers on how I should proceed? Much appreciated.

Comment: One approach would be to create a field say MFClosedxPrevious day on the object then have a daily batch process populate them. Then you could do one query and get all the information you need. Another approach would simply be to query for cases closed in the last 7 days meeting the other criteria within a singly query then iterate over them to populate collections..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a simple aggregate query:

```
AggregateResult[] results = [SELECT COUNT(Id) sum, DAY_ONLY(ClosedDate) dayValue, Assignee__c assignee FROM Case WHERE ClosedDate = LAST_N_DAYS:7 AND Assignee__c IN ('MF','RM','GT','CW') GROUP BY DAY_ONLY(ClosedDate), Assignee__c];
```

You can then loop through the results and assign them appropriately; I'd probably recommend a map to get started:

```
    Map<String, Map<Integer, Decimal>> values = new Map<String, Map<Integer, Decimal>> {
    'MF' => new Map<Integer, Decimal>(),
    'RM' => new Map<Integer, Decimal>(),
    'GT' => new Map<Integer, Decimal>(),
    'CW' => new Map<Integer, Decimal>()
};
for(AggregateResult result: results) {
    Decimal sum = (Decimal)result.get('sum'), dayValue = (Decimal)result.get('dayValue');
    String assignee = (String)result.get('assignee');
    values.get(assignee).put(dayValue, sum);
}
```

Finally, you'd get the values back from your map:

```
Date today = Date.today();
Integer 
    day0 = today.day(), 
    day1 = today.addDays(-1).day(), 
    day2 = today.addDays(-2).day(), 
    day3 = today.addDays(-3).day(), 
    day4 = today.addDays(-4).day(), 
    day5 = today.addDays(-5).day(), 
    day6 = today.addDays(-6).day(), 
    day7 = today.addDays(-7).day();

MFClosedToday = values.get('MF').get(day0) == null? 0: values.get('MF').get(day0) == null;
MFClosed1DayPrevious = values.get('MF').get(day1) == null? 0: values.get('MF').get(day1);
MFClosed2DayPrevious = values.get('MF').get(day2) == null? 0: values.get('MF').get(day2);
MFClosed3DayPrevious = values.get('MF').get(day3) == null? 0: values.get('MF').get(day3);
MFClosed4DayPrevious = values.get('MF').get(day4) == null? 0: values.get('MF').get(day4);
MFClosed5DayPrevious = values.get('MF').get(day5) == null? 0: values.get('MF').get(day5);
MFClosed6DayPrevious = values.get('MF').get(day6) == null? 0: values.get('MF').get(day6);
MFClosed7DayPrevious = values.get('MF').get(day7) == null? 0: values.get('MF').get(day7);
```

And repeat for the rest of your variables.

Alternatively, you could always decide to use the map directly, since it contains the values you need; you will need to be aware that missing keys may exist, so you'll need to check for nulls.

You could also populate the zeroes afterwards using a simple loop:

```
for(String key: values.keySet()) {
    for(Integer index = 0; index < 7; index++) {
        Integer dayValue = Date.Today().addDays(-index).day();
        if(values.get(key).get(dayValue) == null) {
            values.get(key).put(dayValue, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: sfdcfox - does OP need to worry about 'Aggregate query does not support queryMore()' error that can occur on very large orgs?

Comment: I'm getting the error  `Incompatible key type Decimal for Map<Integer,Decimal> at line 309 column 38` which is the `values.get(key).put(dayValue,0);` line

Comment: @SamCousins Try this instead: `values.get(key).put(dayValue.intValue(), 0);`.

Comment: @crop1645 There's less than 200 rows here (a total of 28 rows), so there shouldn't be a problem. It's definitely worth pointing out that the limitation does exist, so if they wanted to do, say, 20 different values across a month per day, then they'd start having issues.

Comment: @sfdcfox Thanks, Finally I'm getting `Incompatible types in ternary operator: Integer, Boolean at line 347 column 40` on `MFClosedToday = values.get('MF').get(day0) == null? 0: values.get('MF').get(day0) == null;` , Could I do the same?

Comment: @SamCousins `MFClosedToday = values.get('MF').get(day0) == null? 0: values.get('MF').get(day0);` The last == null is apparently erroneous.

Answer (score 0):

Getting all cases closed in the last week at once and looping through them to get your counts would save you a lot of queries, and potentially help with your governor limits. However, it would likely use more CPU time which is also a governor limit. You can also only query for 50,000 records in one context, so this might limit you if you have an enormous amount of cases each week.

```
 public void getPerformanceCounts() {
        MFClosedToday = 0;
        MFClosed1DayPrevious = 0;
        ... //intitialize remaining count variables to 0

        Date tdy = System.today();
        List<Case> casesClosedInLastWeek = [SELECT Assignee__c, ClosedDate FROM Case WHERE ClaosedDate < :chartRange[0] AND ClosedDate >= :tdy.addDays(-7)];

        for(case c : casesClosedInLastWeek) {
            if (c.Assignee__c == 'MF') {
                if (c.ClosedDate >= :tdy.addDays(-1)) {
                    MFClosedToday += 1;
                } else if (c.ClosedDate >= :tdy.addDay(-2)) {
                    MFClosed1DayPrevious += 1;
                } else if ... //continue with other days for MF cases

            } else if (c.Assignee__c = 'RM') {
                if (c.ClosedDate >= :tdy.addDays(-1)) {
                    RMClosedToday += 1;
                } else if ...
            }
            ... // continue with GT cases, CW cases
            }
        } 

    }
```